# "On" school or "In" school?

Tags: word-choice

I know it's correct to say "in school", but is it also ok to say "on school"?

My mother tongue is german and if I translate it 1:1 it's "on school" and not "in school".

Comment: Well you can be on school business, or on school property, but you can’t be on school.

Comment: You could literally be on a school entity, but then you would need a determiner to clarify which particular school you were on, i.e., "_on a school_" or "_on my school_" etc.  Basically there would be no correct place for "on school" in traditional context.

Comment: No, it's not. You can't ever rely on translating prepositions 1:1.

Comment: We say *at school* and *in school* (which can mean different things)  but not *on school*. If we climbed to the top of a school building, we could say *on the school (building)*.

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm curious because the standard phrase in German is *in der Schule* rather than *an der Schule*, which to me is limited to learning a specific subject, but when speaking about location you'd use *in* (in German)

Answer (score 1):

No.
Translations are tricky because we say things in different languages differently. In Canadian French we might say "fermé la lumiere" to mean "turn off the light". The word fermé means to close, and close the light would not be correct in English. In English we have the expression ' hit the road', which means it is time to go, usually on a trip by car, but the expression is looser than that. I could suggest, "Let's hit the road. It's time for work." In French, the translation would mean to literally reach down and touch the road surface with a good tap or hit.

Many words and phrases do not literally translate. The only way you could be 'on school' would be to be on school property, like the roof or on the playground. It is simply one of the many peculiarities of English.

Comment: Yes, and I suspect the real reason any tranx software shows the same result for 'in…' or 'on school' is simply that English has no place for 'on school'. It is not needed, ever.